# MonetDB embedded R code debugging

Tags: r, monetdb

In my efforts to work around the issue mentioned here:
[MonetDB connect to GO.db within R code that is run in-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302096/monetdb-connect-to-go-db-within-r-code-that-is-run-in-database)

I went ahead and copied the code from WGCNA that I needed to my own package and installed it. Obviously, I now can load the package without any issues (since I didn't need the GO.db part).

However, I seem to run into another issue:

> Server says '!Error running R expression. Error message: Error in
>   .C("corFast", x = as.double(x), nrow = as.integer(nrow(x)), ncolx =
>   as.integer(ncol(x)),  : '.

I indeed wanted to use the faster cor function from WGCNA, but apparently the C call now creates another issue.
Unfortunately, the message is not informative. I already tried to run the query interactively and adding debug to the statement. This did not provide me with more information.

Is there anything that I can do to increase the verbosity, so that I can debug the proces?

I also tried:

```
options(monetdb.debug.query=F)
```

This resulted in a bit of extra output prior to the query, but no extra output on the error that occurred.

Using the suggestion of Hannes Muehleisen I added:

```
options(monetdb.debug.mapi=T)
```

It does add a little more information, which allowed me to proceed a bit further. I am now stuck with the following error, which seems again truncated.

> QQ: 'SELECT * FROM cor_test();' TX: 'sSELECT * FROM cor_test(); ; RX:
>   '!Error running R expression. Error message: Error in .C("corFast", x
>   = as.double(x), nrow = as.integer(nrow(x)), ncolx = as.integer(ncol(x)),  :  !  "corFast" not available for .C() for
>   package "MRMRF Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :    Unable to
>   execute statement 'SELECT * FROM cor_test();'. Server says '!Error
>   running R expression. Error message: Error in .C("corFast", x =
>   as.double(x), nrow = as.integer(nrow(x)), ncolx = as.integer(ncol(x)),
>   : '.

Comment: will get to this tomorrow sorry for delay

Comment: @HannesMühleisen I think I know what kept you busy yesterday. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a known issue where only the first line of the error message is returned. We should fix this. I always use `stop(whatever)` to return some info from within the UDF.

Comment: Is there a quick and dirty fix that I might be able to make to the source code? (I already compiled it from source before :) )

Comment: actually try to set `options(monetdb.debug.mapi=T)` and see whether you see more output.

Comment: That does provide me with a little more information! Thanks.